# jquery filter methods removes script tags

Tags: jquery

I make an ajax call to some url which return some html and I want to some part of that html somewhere in DOM. So where data is retrieved from server I use filter method to strip off unwanted html and insert the wanted one in DOM. But as it appears the script tags that are inside that wanted html, are removed. I think the filter method is doing something with it. Is there any way to not strip out the script tags ?

Comment: can you share some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery messes with the SCRIPT tags when you pass HTML to $(). It doesn't remove them though -- it simply adds them to the DOM collection produced from your HTML. Try this:

```
    var dom = $(data);

    dom.filter('script').each(function(){
        $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
    });

    $('#mydiv').html(dom.find('#something').html());
```